# MySQL when I run Trigger more than one time I get ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I added this trigger on the table:

```
create table if not exists t_sells(
sellID integer primary key auto_increment,
FKcustID integer, foreign key(FKcustID) 
references t_customers(custID),
FKemployeeID integer, foreign key(FKemployeeID)
references t_employees(employeeID),
FKartID integer, foreign key(FKartID) 
references t_articles(artID),
soldNumber integer,
soldDat date
);

delimiter //
create trigger trig_stockupdate after insert
on t_sell for each row 
begin
declare var_artID integer;
declare var_soldNumber integer;
select FKartID, soldNumber from t_sell
into var_artID, var_soldNumber;
update t_articles set artAmountInStock = (artAmountInStock-var_soldNumber)
where artID = var_artID;
end //
delimiter ;
```

It shall, whenever a new order is inserted into t_verkauf, read how many items were sold and then substract this number from the stock in another table. 
It works fine when I insert the first order, but when I insert a secon time I always get the ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row.

I guess it's something obvious, but I don't find what I did wrong...

P.S. I changed the table-names, variables into english, that it is easier to read for you.

Comment: code indent should also help readability

Comment: I always expect to see some reference to NEW. column names in an insert trigger  - you don't have any so I suggest you reread the manual and change the trigger to dump the select statement and use NEW. column names.